# Save data with entity manager in multiple schemas

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager

I'm working in a project where I have to save the same information in different schemas

As example I have this entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Cliente.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cliente c")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CLIENTE_CLICODIGO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CLIENTE_CLI_CODIGO_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CLIENTE_CLICODIGO_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "cli_codigo")
private Integer cliCodigo;

@Column(name = "cli_activo", columnDefinition = "bool default true")
private Boolean cliActivo = true;
```

And the way to save the data is:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public void guardarCliente(Cliente clienteSeleccionado) throws Exception {
    if (clienteSeleccionado.getCliCodigo() == null) {
        entityManager.persist(clienteSeleccionado);
    } else {
        entityManager.merge(clienteSeleccionado);
    }

}
```

At the moment it works and save in my public schema however I don't know how to save in different schema in the same database.

I was thinking in duplicate entity but when I try it, errors appears

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple persistence contexts, one per schema. Then you can use these context to save/merge the entities.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="schema_1")
EntityManager entityManagerS1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="schema_2")
EntityManager entityManagerS2;

public void guardarCliente(Cliente clienteSeleccionado) throws Exception {
    if (clienteSeleccionado.getCliCodigo() == null) {
        entityManagerS1.persist(clienteSeleccionado);
        entityManagerS2.persist(clienteSeleccionado);
    } else {
        entityManagerS1.merge(clienteSeleccionado);
        entityManagerS1.merge(clienteSeleccionado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, I'm looking in my persistence.xml and I just have defined a persistence-unit. I'm going to add another persistence-unit however, where can define the schema to use for this persistence-unit

Comment: I think you will need another datasource.

Comment: At the moment I have added `hibernate.default_schema` property to the new persistence-unit, what is the role of datasource?

Comment: Could you share your persistence.xml?